# What APIs is the `security` cli using?

Tags: macos, command-line, security

in particular the `execute-with-privileges` subcommand, which uses fingerprint scanning GUI to authenticate and i'm curious whether those could be used if I build a cli.

### Details

`security` is a standard binary that ships with OSX and:

```
security(1)               BSD General Commands Manual              security(1)

NAME
     security -- Command line interface to keychains and Security framework

SYNOPSIS
     security [-hilqv] [-p prompt] [command] [command_options] [command_args]
```

Any pointers or reference to documentation would help!

Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

## AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges

`security` uses the deprecated [AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated) function to implement `execute-with-privileges`:

```
status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth_ref,argv[0], 0, (argc > 1) ? &argv[1] : NULL, &communications_pipe);
```

The function needs an `AuthorizationRef`, which is the part that confirms who the user is. See the [AuthorizationServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/authorization_services) framework. Note that AuthorizationServices are not available to sandboxed applications on macOS.

### Open Source

[`security` is open source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-59306.80.4/SecurityTool/macOS/security.c.auto.html) and available on https://opensource.apple.com

macOS 10.15.3's [Security-59306.80.4](https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10153.html) bundle contains the source code:

- Security-59306.80.4/SecurityTool/macOS